# Reverse default Route to private Route and conversely

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mobx

in my application, you can enter the main page only after authorization, respectively, the login page is always the first if the user is not authorized, I have private routs that are not allowed if the user is not authorized, and one normal route to the login page, since There will be a lot of private routs, I would like to do something, like a reverse, ie, I would use a private route once, and on other pages that require authorization to go there, put an ordinary route, how can this be achieved?

```
const PrivateRoute = ({store, component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return (
     <Route
       {...rest}
       render={(props)=>
        localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
           <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
           <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
         )
       }
    />
 )

 export const Routes = () => {
    return (
       <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
          {/* ...more PrivateRoutes */}
       </Switch>
      );
   };
```

i need something like this

````
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Login} />
<Route path="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
{/* ...more Routes*/}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your main goal is to reduce usage of PrivateRouter variable, so you can try this approach: use different routes for logged / not logged user

```
const App = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // check if user is logged in
  }, []);

  return (
    <Switch>
      {!isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>{/* Routes for logged user*/}</>
      )}
    </Switch>
  );
};
``
```